# createDraftReply not updating the bcc in gmail addon app script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am developing a simple gmail addon in which i have few buttons that have id related to each of them. I want to create a draft and using those id's update the bcc part of the draft. Code for createReply draft is as following:

```
function createReplyDraft(e){
  // Activate temporary Gmail scopes, in this case to allow
    // a reply to be drafted.
     var accessToken = e.gmail.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
    var messageId = e.gmail.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var currentDraft = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('currentDraft');

    var draft = message.createDraftReply('',
        {
            htmlBody: message.getBody(),
            bcc: e.parameters.caseid+"@bcc.company.com"

        }
    );
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('currentDraft',draft.getId());
    // Return a built draft response. This causes Gmail to present a
    // compose window to the user, pre-filled with the content specified
    // above.
    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(draft).build();

  }
```

**i works fine first time (time of creation of draft) but after that it does not update the bcc instead it removes the bcc part.**

I also tried to use **draft.update** it does the trick but you have to reload the page to see the changes.

Comment: Where does the parameter `caseid` come from? Also, are you aware that script properties are shared among all users using the script ( = Add-on). This can lead to the overwriting of the draft id and if you try to get in your Gmail session a draft with the drive id of another user - this cannot work.

Comment: from onClick funtion of button @ziganotschka
how can we fix it ??

Comment: maybe replacing script properties by user properties will solve the issue? Otherwise you have to create dynamically properties with different names.

Comment: yeah i sorted that out thanks but i still have problem regarding the draft can you help in that matter?